# How to use android network location without Gapps?

Tags: android, gps

Okay, so I removed all of Gapps from my android 4.1 phone.

My GPS can no longer be determined via wifi or towers.
(Is this because networklocation.apk depends on Gapps?)

Does anyone have a solution to enable network location without Gapps?

Comment: What is Gapps? What is networklocation.apk?

Comment: Gapps is the collective term for google application such as google play or google play services.
Networklocation.apk (I think) is the service that is used to identify the phone's location via wifi and telephone masts.

Comment: And what is the programming question or problem?

Comment: Well its two questions, Is as networklocation.apk dependent on any Gapps?
Does anyone know of any alternatives to networklocation.apk?

Comment: Repeat: what has this to do with PROGRAMMING?

Comment: Stop being so obtuse. If you don't know the answer then please refrain from commenting.